# R | ggplot2 | (remove tick marks + remove panel border) but keep axis lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, border-layout, yaxis

novice user here so please be kind and gentle! :)

I am dealing with the following dataset and R script:

```
#Create pvalue ranges
pvalue <- c(".000 - .005",".005 - .010",".010 - .015",".015 - .020",".020 - .025",".025 - .030",".030 - .035",".035 - .040",".040 - .045",".045 - .050")

#Create frequency counts
count <- c(5000,4000,3100,2540,2390,2260,2150,2075,2050,2025)

dat <- data.frame(pvalue = pvalue, count = count)

#Create plot
myPlot <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=pvalue, y=count, group=1)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    geom_vline(xintercept=which(dat$pvalue == '.045 - .050'), linetype = "dashed") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
    ggtitle(paste("Insert Plot Title Here")) +
    labs(x = "insert x-axis title here", y = "insert y-axis title here") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=0.5,family = "TNR")) +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black"),
          axis.line.y = element_line(color="black")) +
    scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)

myPlot
```

The above dataset and R script produce the following plot:

[Note that I do not have enough "points" to embed an image so a link to the image has been created by Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuqic.jpg)

An inspection of the image reveals that the left panel border (or the vertical axis) is missing. I want the left panel border to be included in the plot. However, I want to exclude the tick marks on the left panel border (or the vertical axis). Taken together, my desired plot would

1. include a vertical line for the y-axis,
2. include a horizontal line for the x-axis,
3. remove tick marks along the y-axis (vertical axis)
4. remove the top panel border
5. remove the right panel border

The above R script takes care of #2-5 in this list. However, I have tried and tried and am unable to figure out how to take care of #1 in this list -- despite including the following in my R script:

```
theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black"),
          axis.line.y = element_line(color="black")) +
```

Can somebody help me to produce the desired image? Very much appreciated :)

Comment: `dat` is not created here so I we can't really help you without at least *some* data...

Comment: I presume `dat <- data.frame(pvalue = pvalue, count = count)`

Comment: @JeanneChaudanson I think someone else updated my code to include dat <- data.frame(pvalue = pvalue, count = count). Thank you to this person for doing this and apologies for my oversight!

Comment: Thank you @Axeman for adding to my code :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `scale_y_discrete(breaks = NULL)` breaks the y axis, as it interpret as show nothing.

Removing that line we have the `y axis` and we can then remove `ticks` and `text`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=pvalue, y=count, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=which(dat$pvalue == '.045 - .050'), linetype = "dashed") +
  ggtitle(paste("Insert Plot Title Here")) +
  labs(x = "insert x-axis title here", y = "insert y-axis title here") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=0.5,family = "TNR"),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),        ## <- this line
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),         ## <- and this line
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Lines for the x- & y-axis don't appear when I run the code that you provided. Otherwise, the plot looks good. In addition, I get the following warning messages. Any suggestions? > Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
2: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
3: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database

Comment: Changing "axis.line = element_line(),"  to "axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"), axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black")<" fixed my issue. Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: The warning is most likely due to `element_text(lineheight=0.5,family = "TNR")`, which comes from your own code.